# UINavigationController UIToolBar does not show up in my views

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My UINavigationController contains a UIToolBar with 3 UIBarBottomItems - It has all been drag/drop designed in the storyboard. I want this UIToolbar to be shared on all my views. I have therefore set checked the "shows toolbar". But when I run it the UIToolBar is empty in all of my views. What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread but I've just been struggling with this for a couple hours and finally figured out what was wrong.  It was something simple so thought I would share.  I was calling `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];` in viewDidLoad.  The problem was that viewDidLoad is called before the view controller is pushed onto the navigationController so self.navigationController is nil.  I moved the code to viewWillAppear: method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController have default toolbar. which you can use. you can use following code

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

in the topmost view controller and

```
[self setToolbarItems:items];
```

in all your view controllers, where items is an NSArray of that view controller's toolbar items.

Comment: I tried setting this in my viewdidload method of my first view - [self setToolbarItems:self.navigationController.toolbar.items];

Comment: but still the uitoolbar is empty

Answer (score 0):

select your initial view controller in the storyboard and embed it in navigation controller.
now all your pages should have the navigation bar.. if u manually dragged dropped the previous bars when u run the program it'll show both...
You'll have to remove the old ones and then modify the new one as required.

Comment: If I go to my first view (the one after the uinavigationcontroller) and check "initial scene" to "is initial view controller" then the uitoolbar doesn't even show - how do I embed it in the navigation controller using the storyboard ?

Comment: Set the navigation controller as initial scene.
You'll have what you want in each viewcontroller's navigation bar individually, if you want the same thing then you gotta do it for all, or you can write the code for 1 controller and use it in each controller's init or viewDidLoad.